# posix regexp to split a table

Tags: regex, postgresql, posix

I'm currently working on data migration in PostgreSQL. Since I'm new to posix regular expressions, I'm having some trouble with a simple pattern and would appreciate your help.

I want to have a regular expression split my table on each alphanumeric char in a column, eg. when a column contains a string `'abc'` I'd like to split it into 3 rows: `['a', 'b', 'c']`. I need a regexp for that

The second case is a little more complicated, I'd like to split an expression `'105AB'` into `['105A', '105B']`, I'd like to copy the numbers at the beginning of the string and split the table on uppercase letters, in the end joining the number with exactly 1 uppercase letter.

the function I'll be using is probably `regexp_split_to_table(string, regexp)`

I'm intentionally providing very little data not to confuse anyone, since what I posted is the essence of the problem. If you need more information please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first was already solved by you:

```
select regexp_split_to_table(s, ''), i
from (values
    ('abc', 1),
    ('def', 2)
) s(s, i);
 regexp_split_to_table | i 
-----------------------+---
 a                     | 1
 b                     | 1
 c                     | 1
 d                     | 2
 e                     | 2
 f                     | 2
```

In the second case you don't say if the numerics are always the first tree characters:

```
select
    left(s, 3) || regexp_split_to_table(substring(s from 4), ''), i
from (values
    ('105AB', 1),
    ('106CD', 2)
) s(s, i);
 ?column? | i 
----------+---
 105A     | 1
 105B     | 1
 106C     | 2
 106D     | 2
```

For a variable number of numerics:

```
select n || a, i
from (
    select
        substring(s, '^\d{1,3}') n,
        regexp_split_to_table(substring(s, '[A-Z]+'), '') a,
        i
    from (values
        ('105AB', 1),
        ('106CD', 2)
    ) s(s, i)
) s;
 ?column? | i 
----------+---
 105A     | 1
 105B     | 1
 106C     | 2
 106D     | 2
```

Comment: the first solution works, thanks

As for the second one, length of numerics is variable (1-3), but your idea has pushed me forward, I'll try to use regexp_replace on this and probably work out the solution in the next 15 minutes :)

thanks a lot

Comment: @fetta Check my edited answer if you didn't already work it out.

Comment: I have done it in a diffrent way:

`regexp_replace(t2.oddzial, '[~A-Za-z]+', '') || regexp_split_to_table(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(t2.oddzial, '[0-9]+', ''), '[~a-z]+', ''), '') odd`

where t2.oddzial is column that I'm splitting

thanks again :)